# How do I properly initialize array fields within a `Structure` in JNA?

Tags: java, c, jna

I have a Struct in C i want to represent in java with JNA:

```
typedef struct SmallStrcut {
     unit32_t a[128];
}

typedef struct BigStruct {
     SmallStruct b;
     SmallStruct c;
}
```

And the following function:

```
void getBigStruct(BigStruct bigStruct);
```

I have the following Structs in Java: 
 SmallStruct:

```
public class SmallStruct extends Structure {
      public static ByValue extends SmallStruct implements Structure.ByValue {
           public int a[];
           public ByValue() {}
      }
}
```

BigStruct:

```
public class BigStruct extends Structure {
        public static ByValue extends BigStruct implements Structure.ByValue {
               public SmallStruct b;
               public SmallStruct c;
               public ByValue() {}
          }
```

This is my main:

```
BigStruct.ByValue big = new BigStruct.ByValue();
SmallStruct.ByValue x1 = new SmallStruct.ByValue();
x1.a = new int[128];
x1.a[0] = 123;
SmallStruct.ByValue x2 = new SmallStruct.ByValue();
x2.a = new int[128];
x2.a[0] = 456;

big.b = x1;
big.c = x2;
```

And when i debug this code i watched the BigStruct object and only the
b member is initialized. c array is all zero. 
Its like the first SmallStruct ovverides the second SmallStruct memory area.

How can i transfer the two SmallStruct to construct the BigStruct properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining `Structure` fields, JNA defaults to by value semantics, so you can just use `Structure`.

It is up to you to initialize any array fields within your `Structure`, since JNA has no way of knowing how big you want them to be.

```
public class SmallStruct extends Structure {
   public int a[] = new int[128];
}
```

Note that the contents of those arrays will not by synched with native memory until you call `Structure.read()` or `Structure.write()` (these calls are performed automatically by JNA when you call a native method which uses a `Structure` argument).